# Example of C++ code optimization for parallel computing

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

I'm trying to understand optimization routines. I'm focusing on the most critical part of my code (the code has some cycles of length "nc" and one cycle of length "np", where number "np" is much larger then "nc"). I present part of the code in here. The rest of code is not very essential in % of computational time so i prefer code purify in the rest of the algorithm. However, the critical cycle with "np" length is a pretty simple piece of code and it can be parallelized. So it will not hurt if i rewrite this part into some more effective and less clear version (maybe into SSE instructions). I'm using a gcc compiler, c++ code, and OpenMP parallelization.

This code is part of the well known [particle-in-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-in-cell) algorithm (and this one is also basic one). I'm trying to learn code optimization on this version (so my goal is not to have effective PIC algorithm only, because it is already written in thousand variants, but i want to bring some demonstrative example for code optimization also). I'm trying to do some work but i am not very sure if i solved all optimization properties correctly.

```
const int NT = ...; // number of threads (in two versions: about 6 or about 30)
const int np = 10000000; // np is about 1000-10000 times larger than nc commonly
const int nc = 10000;
const int step = 1000;

float u[np], x[np];
float a[nc], a_lin[nc], rho_full[NT][nc], rho_diff[NT][nc] , weight[nc];

int p,num;

for ( i = 0 ; i<step ;  i++) {

// *** 
// *** some not very time consuming code for calculation 
// *** a, a_lin from values of rho_full and rho_diff

#pragma omp for private(p,num)
for ( k = np ; --k ; ) {

    num = omp_get_thread_num();

    p = (int) x[k];
    u[k] += a[p] + a_lin[p] * (x[k] - p);
    x[k] += u[k];

    if (x[k]<0 ) {x[k]+=nc;} else
    if (x[k]>nc) {x[k]-=nc;};

    p = (int) x[k];
    rho_full[num][p] += weight[k];
    rho_diff[num][p] += weight[k] * (x[k] - p);

    }
};
```

I realize this has problems:

**1)** (main question) I use set of arrays `rho_full[num][p]` where `num` is index for each thread. After computation i just summarize this arrays (`rho_full[0][p] + rho_full[1][p] + rho_full[2][p] ...`). The reason is avoidance of writing into same part of array with two different threads. I am not very sure if this way is an effective solution (note that number "nc" is relatively small, so number of operations with "np" is still probably most essential)

**2)** (also important question) I need to read `x[k]` many times and it's also changed many times. Maybe its better to read this value into some register and then forget whole x array or fix some pointer in here. After all calculation i can call `x[k]` array again and store obtained value. I believe that compiler do this work for me but i am not very sure because i used modification of `x[k]` in the center of algorithm. So the compiler probably do some effective work on their own but maybe in this version it call more times then nessesary becouse more then ones I swich calling and storing this value.

**3)** (probably not relevant) The code works with integer part and remainder below decimal point part. It needs both of this values. I identify integer part as `p = (int) x` and remainder as `x - p`. I calculate this routine at the begin and also in the end of cycle interior. One can see that this spliting can be stored somewhere and used at next step (i mean step at `i` index). Do you thing that following version is better? I store integral and remainder part at arrays of x instead of whole value x.

```
int x_int[np];
float x_rem[np];
//...

for ( k = np ; --k ; ) {

    num = omp_get_thread_num();

    u[k] += a[x_int[k]] + a_lin[x_int[k]] * x_rem[k];
    x_rem[k] += u[k];

    p = (int) x_rem[k];   // *** This part is added into code for simplify the rest.
    x_int[k] += p;        // *** And maybe there is a better way how to realize
    x_rem[k] -= p;        // *** this "pushing correction".

    if (x_int[k]<0 ) {x_int[k]+=nc;} else
    if (x_int[k]>nc) {x_int[k]-=nc;};

    rho_full[num][x_int[k]] += weight[k];
    rho_diff[num][x_int[k]] += weight[k] * x_rem[k];

    }
};
```

Comment: instead of having an array entry for each thread, have you thought about using [thread local](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OMP reduction](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION) for your for loop:

```
int result = 0;

#pragma omp for nowait reduction(+:result) 
for ( k = np ; --k ; ) {

    num = omp_get_thread_num();

    p = (int) x[k];
    u[k] += a[p] + a_lin[p] * (x[k] - p);
    x[k] += u[k];

    if (x[k]<0 ) {x[k]+=nc;} else
    if (x[k]>nc) {x[k]-=nc;};

    p = (int) x[k];
    result += weight[k] + weight[k] * (x[k] - p);

}
```

Comment: Actually, I can't. I can use OMP reduction just for some type variables as floats, integers, ... but not for arrays :/